# Проверить, является ли символ русской буквой

Tags: c++, строки, кодировка

**Я использую кодировку UTF8 и `setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian")`**
В строке лежат символы, надо найти все, являющиеся русскими буквами. Как это сделать? Я уже пробовал делать строку из этого символа и подобные методы, но если просто "оторвать" символ, записанный в UTF8 от остальной строки, то получится неизвестно что, тк коды часто не влезают в один байт. Единственное решение, которое я нашел, использует `std::wstring`, но хотелось бы как-нибудь обойтись без него. Возможно ли?

Comment: Конечно. Надо анализировать несколько бит каждой пары байтов. Подробности в вике.

Comment: Для этого следует воспользоваться библиотекой ICU.

Comment: @user7860670 можно поподробнее?

Comment: Развлекался я этим когда-то. Можете посмотреть [ucsutf.h](https://pastebin.com/gg6Xe9KL) и [ucsutf.c](https://pastebin.com/iCC2k7RW)

Comment: @verybadcoder, с ответом разобрались, он помог?

Comment: @avp да, спасибо большое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот простой пример, как это сделать

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>


// Returns Unicode of cyrillic or 0
// see https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF
int
is_rus_letter (const char *s, int only_rus)
{
  if ((*s & 0xe0) != 0xc0)
    return 0;
  if ((s[1] & 0xc0) != 0x80)
    return 0;
  uint32_t uc = ((s[0] & 0x1f) << 6) | (s[1] & 0x3f); // 5 bits `s[0]` and 6 bits `s[1]`

  if (uc < 0x400 || uc > 0x4ff)
    return 0; // not cyrillic
  if (only_rus) 
    if ((uc < 0x410 || uc > 0x44f) && // А - Я; а - я
        !(uc == 0x401 || // Ё
          uc == 0x451)) // ё
      return 0;
        
  return uc;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{

  char s[LINE_MAX + 1];

  printf("enter lines (not longer %d bytes)\n", LINE_MAX);
  while (fgets(s, LINE_MAX, stdin)) {
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
      int uc;
      if ((uc = is_rus_letter(s + i, 1))) {
        n++;
        char r[3]; r[0] = s[i], r[1] = s[i + 1]; r[2] = 0;
        printf("in pos %d rus 0x%03x '%s'\n", i, uc, r);
      }
    }
    printf("%d rus letters\n", n);
  }
  
  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Если что-то не понятно, спрашивайте

Comment: А за что минус-то?

Comment: @VladD, наверное кто-то чистый Си сильно не любит

Comment: Кстати, мне недавно попалась задача найти в тексте (.NET, UTF-16) все смайлы (emoji). Это оказалось совсем не тривиально, рантайм-библиотека не спасает.

Comment: @VladD, в utf-16 эмоджи, наверное, суррогатные пары? С ними всегда проблема

Comment: Намного хуже, emoji — это последовательности unicode codepoint-ов, соединённые при помощи ZWNJ, а суррогатные пары лишь кодируют один codepoint.

Comment: То есть длина одного emoji в байтах не ограничена сверху

Comment: @VladD, вот этот https://stackoverflow.com/a/34425890/7286264 случай? Правда, тут zwnj нет

Comment: Это ещё простой случай, тут всего один codepoint U+1F601. Unicode — это вообще бездна.

Comment: То есть первый шаг — это превратить текст в последовательность codepoint-ов, а дальше разбивать на grapheme cluster’ы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132262/discussion-between-avp-and-vladd).